# Authentication Failure using Spring Boot OAuth 2.0 with Azure B2C

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, spring-security, azure-active-directory

I am trying to use Microsoft Azure Ad with Spring Boot for authentication and authorization of web application. I am following steps described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory.

I am getting following error while authentication,

```
2021-07-12 15:15:24,789 ERROR [ip= rq= ep=] [DirectJDKLog.java:175][log:http-nio-8080-exec-3] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.convert(Lorg/springframework/security/oauth2/client/endpoint/AbstractOAuth2AuthorizationGrantRequest;)Lorg/springframework/http/RequestEntity;
    at com.azure.spring.common.AbstractOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.convert(AbstractOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.java:30)
    at com.azure.spring.aad.webapp.AADOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.convert(AADOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.java:29)
    at com.azure.spring.aad.webapp.AADOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.convert(AADOAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter.java:16)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java:77)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.getResponse(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at com.azure.spring.aad.webapp.AADHandleConditionalAccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AADHandleConditionalAccessFilter.java:41)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Versions I am using**

- implementation group: 'com.azure.spring', name: 'azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory', version: '3.6.1'
- implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client', version: '2.5.2'
- implementation group: 'com.nimbusds', name: 'nimbus-jose-jwt', version: '9.10.1'
- id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.7'

**Security Configuration -**

```
    @Profile(LocalProfile.PRESENT)
    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public static class AADSecurityConfiguration
        extends AADWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {
        @Value("${tenant-id}")
        private String TENANT_ID;

        @Value("${azure.activedirectory.client-id}")
        private String CLIENT_ID;

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web)
            throws Exception
        {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/health");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception
        {
            log.info("Configuring AAD security.");
            log.info(String.format("TENANT_ID: %s", TENANT_ID));
            log.info(String.format("CLIENT_ID: %s", CLIENT_ID));
            super.configure(http);
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/callback/", "/webjars/**", "/error**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
            log.warn("Configured AAD security configuration.");
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you have a version mismatch. Can you share your build.gradle or pom.xml?

Comment: Is this issue resolved? if it resolved can you please share the config/code changes here?

Comment: it was an issue related to version of dependencies I was using. Here is the list of dependencies now - group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '2.2.6.RELEASE' // OAuth2.0
            group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client', version: '2.4.2'
            group: 'com.nimbusds', name: 'nimbus-jose-jwt', version: '8.22.1'
            group: 'com.azure.spring', name: 'azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory', version: '3.4.0'
            compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-keyvault', version:'1.0.0'